# "Invalid OpenID transaction" when signing into Launchpad

Tags: firefox, launchpad, logging

When I click on the "Log in / Register" link on the website https://launchpad.net, I always arrive on a blank page only displaying "Invalid OpenID transaction". This happens every time in Firefox, but never in Chromium nor in Epiphany.

Where does that come from and how do I fix it ?

Comment: Did you try to close your browser completely and then try again?

Comment: Yes : it happens always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to accept cookies for the website, of course ...

My browser rejects them by default. I feel really dummy.

Comment: what do you mean accept cookies? This is no solution. Why would we change some default browser settings in order to make this work? I have not explicitly set anything to be blocked or rejected...